# alphabetical order in bibtex with accented words

Tags: bibtex, accents

I have two entries in my bibliography file that are ordered incorrectly and I think the accent has everyting to do with it. Among other stuff I have two entries in the bibliography file:

```
@Article{ku,
  Title                    = {Comprensión del concepto de base de un espacio vectorial desde el punto de vista de la teoría {APOE}},
  Author                   = {Darly Kú and María Trigueros and Asuman Oktaç},
  Year                     = {2008},
}
@PhdThesis{karrer,
  Title                    = {Articulação entre Álgebra Linear e Geometria - Um Estudo sobre as Transformações Lineares na Perspectiva dos Registros de Representação Semiótica},
  Author                   = {Monica Karrer},
  Year                     = {2006},
}
```

The right alphabetical order would be Karrer first and then Kú, but I get it the other way around. How can I make bibtex to treat ú like u when ordering the bibliography?

Comment: `bibtex` cant' handle UTF-8 encoded `.bib` files.  See [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743) for how to handle accented characters with `bibtex`. For sorting issues with standard `bibtex` see [Strange problem with BibTeX sorting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97062). You might want to consider switching to `biblatex` and `biber` which can handle such files (and sort them correctly) out of the box. See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25702)

Comment: Please post a minimal working example so we know how exactly you set up your bibliography.

Comment: Thank you @Alan-Munn The link Strange problem with Bibtex sorting help me solve the problem!

Comment: You could give a try at `biber` which can handle `utf8`.