# Natbib numbers order

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm having some trouble with BibTeX. The code below makes references in author-year order, but for references with same author and year order is arbitrary. Any solution? Thanks :D

```
\documentclass{thesis}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[a4paper,top=4cm,bottom=4cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\bibliographystyle{siam}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\frenchspacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing




\newcommand{\cit}[1]{``#1''}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage 
\nocite{*}
\renewcommand\bibsection{\subsection*{UNdocs}}
\bibliography{un}
\bibliographystyle{siam}


\end{document}

Entry examples:
@Proceedings{unmik2,
title = {On the Authority of the Interim Administration in Kosovo},
year = {1999},
address = {Pristina},
organization = {UNMIK [United Nations Interim Administration Mission in Kosovo]},
note = {U.N. Doc. UNMIK/REG/1999/1},
}

@Proceedings{unmik3,
title = {On the Appointment and Removal from Office of Judges and Prosecutors},
year = {1999},
address = {Pristina},
organization = {UNMIK [United Nations Interim Administration Mission in Kosovo]},
note = {U.N. Doc. UNMIK/REG/1999/7},
}
```

Here's two entry in the .bib file order. When I compile they appear in a random order while I'd like the imput order.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable. The class and bibliography files are missing.

Comment: It is! There're both class (thesis) and .bib file (bibliography=un).

Comment: Could you give a couple of examples of bib entries whose sorting order isn't currently to your liking? Please also indicate what sorting order to do prefer in such cases.

Comment: Added examples!

Comment: Thanks for posting a couple of example entries. The ordering performed by BibTeX is *not* random. First, note that both entries are missing a required field, viz., the `author` field. Note that the year of publication of both entries is the same, so that field doesn't offer a sorting clue either. Without an author, BibTeX will look to the `title` field to perform its sorting job. Since "Appointment" precedes "Authority", alphabetically speaking, entry `unmik3` is typeset before entry `unmik2`.

Comment: Oh thanks, so obvious! However, proceedings entry has not an 'author' field. Any suggestion? Maybe I can change proceedings into another entry type!

Comment: Sorry about the class file comment. For some reason it is not included in TeX Live, but I should have checked CTAN. (Anyway, the issue doesn't seem to depend on the document class.)

Comment: You can change the order of entries in the output by adding invisible text to `title` fields (or whatever field is used for sorting in a particular bibliography style) as suggested in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97272/23160).

Comment: It works, thank you so much! I'll try with biblatex as well